# sum of all attributes for number input type

Tags: javascript, html

I have a collapsible button with around 10 input type number fields with max and min attribute. like this

```
<div id="demoX1" class="collapse"> 
<table>
<tr><td>ABC</td><td><input type="number" min="0"  max= "1" onblur="getTotal()"name="cm"></td>
</tr>
<tr><td>XYZ</td> <td><input type="number" min="0" max= "3" onblur="getTotal()"name="cm"></td>
</tr>
<tr><td>PQR</td> <td><input type="number" min="0" max="1" onblur="getTotal()" name="cm"></td>  
</tr>
</table>
</div>
<input type= "text" id="total1" disabled/>
```

I want to get sum of all the max attribute value. Also if could disable any input on run-time and ignore its value in sum. I tried embedding onblur function in each of them and used function below for the same : onblur()

```
var arr1 = document.getElementsByName('cm').getAttribute("max");
var overAll= 0;
for(var i=0;i<arr1.length;i++){
    if(parseInt(arr1[i].value))
        overAll += parseInt(arr1[i].value);
}
document.getElementById('total1').value = overAll;
```

Comment: There's no PHP here, don't spam irrelevant tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getElementsByName` returns a collection, but you can only call `getAttribute()` on a single element. You need to do that in the loop, not when assigning to `arr1`.

And the value you want is in the `max` attribute, not in the `value`.

```js
var arr1 = document.getElementsByName('cm');
var overAll = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
  var max = arr1[i].getAttribute('max');
  if (max) {
    overAll += parseInt(max, 10);
  }
}
document.getElementById('total1').value = overAll;
```

```html
<div id="demoX1" class="collapse">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>ABC</td>
      <td><input type="number" min="0" max="1" name="cm"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>XYZ</td>
      <td><input type="number" min="0" max="3" name="cm"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>PQR</td>
      <td><input type="number" min="0" max="1" name="cm"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<input type="text" id="total1" disabled/>
```

Comment: Got it. Thank. Also can we disable any of them on run-time? So that it wont add up. something like putting up a disabled tag on runtime and then in this script add condition to not take disabled value.

Comment: Sure. You can do `if (!arr[i].disabled)`